# Story about unlucky colonist

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I remember short sci-fi story about man, who was selected to be a colonist on some planet. He hadn't any superhuman abilities, excluding one - he was extremaly unlucky. Because of some colonization paradigm, sending people like him had a purpose - it allowed to see if a "normal" man can survive on a colonized planet.

It was story from short story collection of some American writer from 70s - 80s.

Comment: Could it be the same as [this one](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/37987/19561)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to SQB comment I found out this story - it is "Minimum Man" by Robert Sheckley. Similar question was already asked [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/37987/short-story-about-a-test-subject-pioneering-with-robot-help-that-becomes-less-he).